# modman tutorial for newbies

Tags: modman

I just downloaded modman using the installer script. It's now located in
/home/user/bin/modman
My root is 
/home/user/html

I've tested it and I can view help and tutorial but I'm feeling special right now because I'm not exactly sure how to proceed from here.

I'm not sure if init is used to tell modman where magento root is or where the modules will be.

Then when you actually want to install I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use link or deploy.
And if I want to remove a module the remove command says deletes files so would that be used if I had installed using --copy instead of link/deploy

How else would you uninstall and remove the synlinks that were created?

Thanks

Comment: [tutorial](http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=github+modman+tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the following are the modman commands.

- init (creates .modman directory and should be done in magento root)
- link (creates symlinks)
- deploy (update symlinks)
- deploy-all (updates all modules)
- repair (repairs all symlinks)
- clean (removes all dead symlinks)
- create (creates a modman file for an existing module)
- clone (clones a git repository)